# Library exception in GWT client-side

Tags: exception, gwt

As I know, GWT needs that code that will be used on client side to be on the XXX.client package. I also know that is possible to configure this path, allowing other client-side code to be outside this package.

However, I can connect this to solve my problem: I'm writing a library that automate some code I'll be using many times over more than one application. This library has an Exception class that is used in the client-side (RCP methods throws it). How can I inform GWT that this class need to be converted to translatable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a module definition file for the library you want to share between projects.  In the module file you can specify multiple `<source path="/path/to/source/" />` elements.  The `Exception` class you want to include must have its source code somewhere in one of those paths.

Once you've created the module for the library, each project needs to "inherit" it with an `<inherits name="com.you.libraryname" />` element in *its* module definition file.

You'll have to google for more specifics, but that's the gist of it!

Comment: Another option would be to build a custom copy of that class using `<super-source />`, if for some reason you do not want to send that exact class to the client - that, coupled with at custom field serializer. http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml and http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideCustomSerialization